# How to see output on console in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am running my project on iPhone simulator. I want to see my NSlog("") output on console. I am new with this interface, How will I see output on console when I am running on simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the menu bar , select run option, it leads to a drop menu, there you have to select console.

Run---> Console

Answer (score 0):

The console output is visible in Xcode. Output is logged while running the app on the Simulator from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You have already given answer to your question, Use **NSLog()** to print on console

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps in XCode

Go to Menu Run -> Console, you will see the console output

Answer (score 0):

Hit Cmd+Shift+R in Xcode <= 3.x

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4, it's showed as in the screenshot:
[image]

It's the black bold text, showing an error log. Using NSLog displays the text you described in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XCode4 then press "command + shift + y" to see your NSLog(@"") on consol and XCode is not XCode4 then press "command + control + r" to see your NSLog(@"") on consol.